# ttk.Progressbar being duplicated

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a peculiar problem when displaying a widget containing a `tkinter.StringVar` variable.

This happens whether or not I use frames to locate the variable.

In brief, I have three non-variable labels, one variable label, a progressbar and two buttons all gridded vertically (the button are side by side though (irrelevant but supplied for completeness).

When the variable is changed programmatically, concatenating a new character ('\n) and more text, the variable shows the extra lines, but duplicate progressbars and buttons are displayed:

[image: screen shots of progressbar at various stages]

(Separate images [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t3nc25z73ww2tlc/AACAw1f2ymySzRq0LQQCmkZDa?dl=0)).

Interesting note: This does not happen if the `'\n'` is not added.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class rtGetPaths(tk.Frame):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.root = root

        # Get the system separator
        self.path_sep = os.pathsep
        # Find the root on the drive
        self.root_id = os.path.abspath(os.sep)
        self.data = [(os.path.join('C:', 'Program Files', 'App_1.exe')),
                     (os.path.join('C:', 'Program Files', 'App_2.exe')),
                     (os.path.join('C:', 'Program Files', 'App_3.exe')),
                     (os.path.join('C:', 'Program Files', 'App_4.exe'))
                    ]

        self.locns = []

        self.root.title('Get Paths')

        self.gpw_l1 = tk.Label(self.root, text='Searching for apps')
        self.gpw_l2 = tk.Label(self.root, text='This may take some time')
        self.gpw_l3 = tk.Label(self.root, text='Please be patient')

        self.gpw_found_l_svar = tk.StringVar()
        self.gpw_found_l_svar.set('')
        self.gpw_found_l = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.gpw_found_l_svar)

        self.gpw_pb_ivar = tk.IntVar()
        self.gpw_pb_ivar.set(0)
        self.gpw_pb_length = 350
        self.gpw_pb_max = 5
        self.gpw_pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.root,
                                      mode='determinate',
                                      maximum=self.gpw_pb_max,
                                      length=self.gpw_pb_length,
                                      variable=self.gpw_pb_ivar)

        self.gpw_exit_b = tk.Button(self.root,
                                    text='Exit',
                                    command=sys.exit)
        self.gpw_continue_b = tk.Button(self.root,
                                        text='Continue',
                                        command=self.gpw_action_continue_b)

        row = 0
        self.gpw_l1.grid(row=row, columnspan=2)
        row += 1
        self.gpw_l2.grid(row=row, columnspan=2)
        row += 1
        self.gpw_l3.grid(row=row, columnspan=2)
        row += 1
        self.gpw_found_l.grid(row=row, columnspan=2)
        row += 1
        self.gpw_pb.grid(row=row, columnspan=2)
        row += 1
        self.gpw_exit_b.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.gpw_continue_b.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='ew')

        self.gpw_found_l.grid_remove()

        self.root.geometry('+100+200')

    def gpw_action_continue_b(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        for file in self.data:
            lookfor = ''
            if 'App_1.exe' in file:
                lookfor = file
            elif 'App_2.exe' in file:
                lookfor = file
            elif 'App_3.exe' in file:
                lookfor = file
            elif 'App_4.exe' in file:
                lookfor = file

            if lookfor != '':
                self.locns.append(lookfor)

                label = self.gpw_found_l_svar.get()
                if 0 < self.gpw_pb_ivar.get() < 5:
                    label = label + '\n'
                label = label + os.path.join(lookfor)
                self.gpw_found_l_svar.set(label)

                self.gpw_pb_ivar.set(self.gpw_pb_ivar.get() + 1)
                if not self.gpw_found_l.winfo_viewable():
                    self.gpw_found_l.grid()

                self.root.update_idletasks()
                time.sleep(1)

        self.gpw_continue_b['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.gpw_pb_ivar.set(self.gpw_pb_max)
        self.root.update_idletasks()

        return

#==============================================================================
#   MAIN (MAIN)
#==============================================================================
def main():
    """ Run the app
    """
    # # Create the screen instance and name it
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = rtGetPaths(root)
    root.mainloop()
    root.quit()

#==============================================================================
#   MAIN (STARTUP)
#==============================================================================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the function name main()
    main()
```

Why is it doing this, and how do I stop it?

Comment: How exactly do do you want things to look? As more files are found, where should it be placed?

Comment: Hi @martineau, The progressbar and buttons move down as the lines are added. I've accepted Tom Fuller's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this problem is occurring, but you can fix it by updating the progress bar each time you change the lable

**The code:**

```
def gpw_action_continue_b(self):

    for file in self.data:
        ...
        self.gpw_pb.update() # this fixes the problem
        self.root.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(1)
```

**Proof it works:**

[image]

Comment: Now that is just pure sorcery!

Lots of thanks, I've spent so long on this. I'd buy you a drink.

Comment: No problem :) glad I could help